# How to Limit UnityAds and Know if a user has clicked and Installed an app through an Ad?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing an game in Unity Engine and I'm almost done implementing UnityAds in my game. But now i wanted to know that how to limit UnityAds Per User and Per Day. And How to know if a user has installed an app through Ads shown.

Comment: The last thing you can't afaik .. it is not your decision which adds are shown to a user and which not .. you only control the amount ... I might be wrong though ^^

Comment: Yes exactly bro! How do i control the Ads shown in my game?

Comment: Count how many add rewards have been given to your user, store the amount somewhere locally with a timestamp (`PlayerPrefs` or simple plain text file etc) and reset after one day ....